# Powershell: how to set the calculation mode of excel application?

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-2003

It is in Excel 2003 VBA

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

I want to achieve the same in Powershell. It is what I did:

```
$excel = New-Object -com Excel.Application
$xlCalculationManual = -4135
$excel.Calculation = $xlCalculationManual
```

Value -4135 is obtained from there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.constants%28v=office.14%29.aspx

It throws an exception:

```
Exception setting "Calculation": "Unable to set the Calculation property of the Application class"
At C:\Documents and Settings\AUser\Desktop\ppp2eikon.ps1:11 char:8
+ $excel. <<<< Calculation = $xlCalculationManual
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

What is the proper way to set this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in VBA, you can't set the calculation mode if there's not at least one open workbook. Error raised is: 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error

Try opening a workbook first.